# Fedora 17 installation error: "ext4 file system check failure on /dev/sda3"

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning, fedora

I am installing Fedora 17, and after creating the hard disk partitions, the installation wizard is throwing an error:

> ext4 file system check failure on /dev/sda3

Again and again, this same error is displayed. I am confused about the reason behind this error.

How can I diagnose this error?

Answer (score 1):

After formatting the partition and before copying the files, the installer probably is doing a fsck, and detecting that the filesystem is inconsistent. There's a good chance that either your installer is borking something or the HD is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Fedora uses the same "anaconda" graphical installer RHEL does, Ctrl-Alt-F1 should get you to a console; if F1 doesn't work, at least one of F2 through F5 should.

From there you can run

```
 fsck /dev/sda3
```

manually, which should give you detailed enough output to start to work out what is going wrong.

Hope this helps!